# Printing Multi-Line Raised Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I am grabbing an update from SVN via Python.

I have this:

```
try: 
    output = subprocess.check_output(svn.update_cmd,
                                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    print output
    print 'finished svn update'

    revision_number = output.split()[-1].rstrip('.') #revision number
    if log_update:
        write_update(revision_number)
    return revision_number
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    raise SVNUpdateError(e.output)
```

When I raise my custom `SNVUpdateError`, I am getting the newlines printing out as `\n`s.

If I `try:except` the `SVNUpdateError`, I can pretty-print the line, but it comes out as stdout, and passes on to the next block of code. I would like to raise the exception, bail out of the task altogether, and print the results from the SVN client as to why things went south without newline and other special characters.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not following.  Why can't you just `sys.stderr.write(e.output)` and then exit (`sys.exit(1)`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your using Python 2.x:

```
# Usually a simpler error message without newlines
print >>sys.stderr, e.message
# If your message is overly complex, with newlines -- pick a line to print and process it
#print >>sys.stderr, e.message.split('\n')[-1].strip()
# Kill the process
sys.exit(1)
```

That will print the message (with restricted newlines in the commented print statement) to stderr and kill the process.

**EDIT**

If the string has actual "\\n" characters instead of special character "\n" in the string (which means someone most likely has a type somewhere in string creation), you could do a simple string replacement before printing:

```
print >>sys.stderr, malformatedStr.replace("\\n", "\n")
```

Comment: Thats good. You gave me what I was asking for; an error without newlines. I guess that's a start, but I was thinking more along the lines of printing the newlines, not the special char `\n`.

Comment: @Droogans Does my edits answer your full question now? Your wording was slightly unclear in your original post and I wasn't sure if you wanted a shorter string or a reformatted string.

Comment: Your edits are the difference between interpreting `"abc\nabc"` and `print "abc\nabc"`. I want the secone one for my exception's output.

Comment: @Droogans Your statement doesn't make sense. The print command has an output to console, a string has no 'output' but can be returned. "\n" represents a newline, "\\n" represents the string literal character '\' followed by character 'n'. Printing any string with "\n" in it will always print the newlines as newlines, but "\\n" will show up as "\n" in the console. Is that you want "\\n" in the console to be seen as a newline or "\n" to appear as something other than a newline or something else? My original answer does the first, my edits the second. I don't see what you which to achieve.